# Cross platform program to get an iOS app to android/google play store?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, apportable, myappconverter

I only plan to do this once since I've moved on to a better game engine, but I currently have an app that is on the apple store that I want to get onto the Google play store. It was created in xcode and I've tried to use Apportable a few times but they seem to be pretty reluctant to both help and well... work. i've tried myappconverter and it's not exactly what I was looking for because I'm not experienced in java so when it converted the code and gave me a whole bunch of errors, I wasn't sure how to fix all of them. I spent several hours trying to get that to work, but I couldn't do it with so little knowledge of eclipse/java. Marmalade seemed...alright, but wasn't very good as well.

Are there any programs out there to essentially wrap the code so there is virtually nothing to do when it comes out to be used for android that are also reliable?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a program to port a game from iOS to android. I assume you using OpenGLES to code your game? If yes, Android supports OpenGLES 2 as well.

If you use Unity or something similar, then it's possible to port your project to another platform.